# Storing RLMResults instead of re-fetching

Tags: ios, objective-c, multithreading, concurrency, realm

I've just started using Realm for Objective-C, I've used Realm for Swift before and I can't remember having any problems with it.

I want to store the fetched objects and convert them to RLMObjects/NSMutableArrays and have them as ViewController's properties, so I won't have to fetch them again using predicates and descriptors and getting them through a loop to distinct them, because there are lots of data to fetch.

```
RLMResults *results = [Sales allObjects];
NSMutableArray<NSString *> resultsIDs* = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
NSMutableArray<Sales *> *uniqueSales = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
for (Sales *sale in results) {
    NSString *id = sale.id;
    if (![resultsIDs id]) {
        [resultsIDs id];
        [uniqueSales addObject:sale];
    }
}

self.distinctProducts = uniqueSales;
```

I know RLMObjects are not thread-safe but since I add different data to different object models concurrently (and only once when the app launches), keeping a reference to the threads does not seem to be a good idea to me.

Answer (score 0):

Just to clarify, `RLMResults` objects are live, meaning that if their underlying data is changed, they get updated automatically. As a result, there's never really a need to re-query or refresh the same results object.

If you still want to store a custom-sorted list of `RLMObject` instances, the most efficient way would be to create a separate Realm model class that has an `RLMArray` property in which you can then save all of your objects.

For example, maybe calling it a `SalesList` object:

```
RLM_ARRAY_TYPE(Sales)

@interface SalesList : RLMObject
@property RLMArray<Sales *><Sales> *sortedSales;
@end
```

It would then be a matter of simply keeping one `SalesList` object, and adding all of the `Sales` objects you sorted into the `sortedSales` array.